# Building up margins/paddings in blocks/pieces

Tags: html, css, sass

Ideally, I would want to write something in SCSS like this:

```
$small: 1px;
$large: 10px;

.top-margin-1small { margin-top: $small; }
.top-margin-2small { margin-top: 2*$small; }
// ...
.top-margin-9small { margin-top: 9*$small; }

.top-margin-1large { margin-top: $large; }
.top-margin-2large { margin-top: 2*$large; }
// ...
.top-margin-9large { margin-top: 9*$large; }
```

And then **BUILD UP BRICK BY BRICK** whatever margin I like in my HTML like this:

```
<div class="top-margin-1large top-margin-3small">
  foo
</div>
```

The only problem is, this doesn't work because margins cannot be "piled" on "top" of each other. Either the larger one "wins" or the last margin that was specified "wins" (i forgot, which is it?)

Is there any good solution to what I want to do?

Comment: That looks like a hell of a lot of tying presentation to your markup.

Comment: @cimmanon yea i'm starting to think it was a bad idea. A much smarter way would be to just type things like "top-margin: $large + 3*$small;" in whatever element I need it right in the SCSS file, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @cimmanon Did you downvote the question btw?

Comment: If you are building an application where you want to let the user have some control over margin height (for example, in an online WYSIWYG editor), the original question makes sense.  However, if you are styling a single page, this may not be very useful.  All depends on the application and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to do something like:

```
.top-margin-1large-3small {margin-top: $large+3*$small}
```

However, you would need to define 81 rules (9 x 9) with the naming rule being

```
.top-margin-{n}large-{m}small {margin-top: {n}*$large+{m}*$small
```

You may be able to write a loop in SAAS to generate these automatically.